# Can you use NSDateformatter for creating dates with only month and year?

Tags: date, nsdateformatter

I have a data source that gives me dates

```
22017            // means: february 2017
122017           // december 2017
52018            // May 2018
```

i've tried parsing this with format `String` `Myyyy`, which does not get correct dates. I'm now adding a '-' dash before the last 4 letters to correctly separate year and month

```
5-2018
12-2018
```

But the `NSDateformatter` still does not give the correct format when setting `M-yyyy`, and i really don't understand why. Is it just too little information to create a date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does indeed work, but you have to specify exactly if the month has one or two digits

```
let dateArray = ["22017", "122017", "52018"]

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

for string in dateArray {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = string.characters.count == 5 ? "Myyyy" : "MMyyyy"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: string)
    print(date)
}
```